# How to Make Entire Custom Checkbox/Div Clickable -- Not Just the Label + Input

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have custom checkboxes I styled like buttons. When you click the label or input the div around it changes color. However, only the label and input are clickable.

Is there a way to make the entire div/button clickable (i.e. everything inside the border)?

Here's my code:

```css
div.label {  
    border:solid 1px gray;
    line-height:40px;
    height:40px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius:40px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    margin-top:10px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:gray;
    text-align:center;
}

label {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + div {
    border: solid 1px red;
    color: #F00;
}

input:checked + div:before {
    content: "\2713";
}
```

```html
<input id="lists[Travel]" type="checkbox" name="lists[Travel]" />
<div class="label">
    <label for="lists[Travel]">Travel</label> <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer is quite symple: you don't need an additional `div`-element. Actually you can place a `label`-element wherever you want and associate it with an `input`-element of your choice.

You do so by giving the `input`-element an `id`-attribute and associate the `label`-element with a corresponding `for`-attribute.

eg: `<input id="my-input-id">[...]<label for="my-input-id">Label Text</label>`)

> - A `<label>` can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the `for` attribute. Such a control is called the labeled control of the label element. One input can be associated with multiple labels.
> - Labels are not themselves directly associated with forms. They are only indirectly associated with forms through the controls with which they're associated.
> - When a `<label>` is clicked or tapped, and it is associated with a form control, the resulting `click` event is also raised for the associated control.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

```css
label {
    display:block;
    border:solid 1px gray;
    line-height:40px;
    height:40px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius:40px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
    margin-top:10px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    color:gray;
    text-align:center;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
    border: solid 1px red;
    color: #F00;
}

input:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2713 ";
}


/* new stuff */
.check {
    visibility: hidden;
}

input:checked + label .check {
    visibility: visible;
}

input.checkbox:checked + label:before {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<input id="lists[Travel]" type="checkbox" name="lists[Travel]" />
<label for="lists[Travel]">Travel with jump</label>

<!-- alternatively avoid jumps between text of state checked and unchecked -->

<input class="checkbox" id="lists[new]" type="checkbox" name="lists[new]" />
<label for="lists[new]"><span class="check">✓</span> Travel without jump</label>
```

In addition you can fiddle around with the `display: block` of the `<label>`.
But this should be quite simple by giving it `float: left`, `display: inline-block` or whatever to get the desired elements float.

*[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/elstermann/pen/ptjuG?editors=110)*

Comment: Hello, sorry for old dated comment, but can you explain why only the label tag can be used to get that effect? Why I can't handle this with a div instead?
===
edit
I've found the reason on MDN page:

"When a <label> is clicked or tapped, and it is associated with a form control, the resulting click event is also raised for the associated control."

link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: @JoãoVictor thank you very much for the additional authority reference. Just added a quote to my answer. So thank you for helping to enhance the content.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one way to achieve this:

```html
<div onclick="this.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').click()">
  <input type="checkbox" style="pointer-events:none">
  <span>Label</span>
</div>
```

Or if you give the checkbox an `id`:

```html
<div onclick="abc.click()">
  <input id="abc" type="checkbox" style="pointer-events:none">
  <span>Label</span>
</div>
```

You need `pointer-events:none` in this appraoch because otherwise a double-click (causing check and uncheck) happens when you click on the checkbox directly.

Comment: "pointer-events: none" did not work for me with custom bootstrap checkboxes. in onclick, "if (event.target == this) { this.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]').click(); }" fixed it.